# media_handle_upload() progress bar

Tags: uploads, media

I'm using the media_handle_upload() function to upload several type of file in the media section of Wordpress Backend.

Is there an easy way to have a progress bar linked to this function to give some feedbacks to the user ?

---- UPDATE ---

This is how my code works as now.

```
 // Let WordPress handle the upload.
 $attachment_id = media_handle_upload('my_image_upload', $product_id);

 $file_url  = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
 $download_id = md5($file_url);

//this is basically a Wordpress post
$pd_object = new WC_Product_Download();

$pd_object->set_id($download_id);
$pd_object->set_name($file_name);
$pd_object->set_file($file_url);

// Get an instance of the WC_Product object (from a defined product ID)
$product = wc_get_product($product_id); 

// Get existing downloads (if they exist)
$downloads = $product->get_downloads();

// Add the new WC_Product_Download object to the array
$downloads[$download_id] = $pd_object;

// Set the complete downloads array in the product
$product->set_downloads($downloads);

$product->save(); // Save the data in database
```

In this way I can save a Product with a file as an attachment.
I'm trying by adding a spinner at the begging of the code and hide it after the `product->save()` command, I know that is not a progress bar, but my aim is to give some sort of feedback to the user.

Comment: How are you uploading/what have you tried? A quick search got me [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/enabling-ajax-file-uploads-in-your-wordpress-plugin/#show-a-progress-bar-or-text-during-the-upload-process) which explains a way to do it.